# Conditions for link functions in glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, link-function

While studying the glm, I found the conditions for the link function to be confusing for me. Lecture notes I'm studying with say the link function should be monotone and differentiable. I understand why these conditions are the case but what confuses me is to which range the link function should abide with those conditions.

For example, since the range of the count data is $\DeclareMathOperator{\abs}{\mathrm{abs}}(0, \infty)$ and for that range, $\abs(u)$ is monotone and differentiable is it okay to use $g(u)=\abs(u)$ as a link function?  Rr Since $\abs(u)$ is not monotone and not differentiable in range of the whole domain, shouldn't I use it as a link function?

Comment: The link function must be monotonic and differentiable over the range of possible values of $\mu$, where $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution. If $\mu > 0$ then $g(\mu)=$ abs$(\mu)$ is the same as the identity link $g(\mu)=\mu$.